# Cryptography Changes in Android P

Tags: android, cryptography, aes, android-9.0-pie

I have an encrypted messenger app that Android P broke.  In P any call to any call to

```
SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto")
```

will throw NoSuchProviderException.

**EDIT** If we are not supposed to use SHA1PRNG, then what provider are we supposed to use ??

In my app the following method gets such an exception . . .

```
public static AESSeedAndMessage doAESEncrypt(String inString)
    {
        //returnes encrypted message along with UNencrypted seed
        AESSeedAndMessage returnStuff = new AESSeedAndMessage();
        returnStuff.seed = generateAESSeed();  //get a random seed
        byte[] encodedBytes = null;
        // Set up secret key spec for 128-bit AES encryption and decryption
        SecretKeySpec sks = null;
        try 
        {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance( "SHA1PRNG", new CryptoProvider() );

            sr.setSeed(returnStuff.seed.getBytes());
            KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kg.init(128, sr);
            sks = new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");

            // Encode the original data with AES
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
            encodedBytes = c.doFinal(inString.getBytes());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            returnStuff.text = "error";
            return returnStuff;
        }
        returnStuff.text = Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return returnStuff;
}
```

I find quite a bit of material on this issue but I haven't been able to find out what to do to replace the removal of that crypto provider.  What do I need to do in order to make this method work, hopefully, in all versions of Android?

**EDIT FYI**
I had a problem with this code back in Android N when crypto was eliminated and had to add the following class to make it work in N.

```
import java.security.Provider;
/**
 * Created by gary on 12/30/2017.
 */
//this is because Android N eliminated crypto
public class CryptoProvider extends Provider {
    /**
     * Creates a Provider and puts parameters
     */
    public CryptoProvider() {
        super("Crypto", 1.0, "HARMONY (SHA1 digest; SecureRandom; SHA1withDSA signature)");
        put("SecureRandom.SHA1PRNG",
                "org.apache.harmony.security.provider.crypto.SHA1PRNG_SecureRandomImpl");
        put("SecureRandom.SHA1PRNG ImplementedIn", "Software");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully, it is deprecated, and you can see the example from [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html). You can select the instance form the [list](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator).

Comment: If you really need the `SHA1PRNG` you have no choice: include the PRNG implementation into your app. Anyway misusing SHA1PRNG as a key generator is a very bad idea. You should have migrated that code to a `PBEKeySpec` based key generation long time ago.

Comment: kelalaka, it was depreciated in N and is gone in P

Comment: Robert, what I "need" is a code example of getting a random AES key.  Can you point me to a PBEKeySpec implementation?

Comment: `byte [] aesKey = new byte[16]; SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(); sr.nextBytes(aesKey); `

Comment: @Dean: But you are not using a random key, you are using a key that is derived from the content of `inString` (and you are misusing SecureRandom for that).  An example how to derive a key from a password using `PBEKeySpec` you can find e.g. here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/992413/150978

Comment: For backwards compatibility - i.e. to **move away** from it - you could copy the algorithm into your application from an old Android source tree. That way you always have access to the correct algorithm. Note that it changed a few times and **was broken** in the initial versions of Android (I think copied from Apache Harmony or similar - including their mistakes). So in addition to Robert's remark, make sure you get the right version of the source code.

Comment: Oh yuk, that's a terrible hack to get the functionality back,  but I applaud you for it. You can of course put the implementation class anywhere, there is no need to keep it in the Apache Harmony package space.